# Kendo Grid Filter customaization

Tags: javascript, filter, kendo-grid

I have to customize the kendo grid filter event. On applying filter instead of filtering the records based on the available records on the grid i need to requery along with filters.

i.e:

```
Onfilter
{
prevent filtering on existing data()
requery from db and apply filter on that data()
}
```

so i have coded like below.(in document ready)

```
(document).ready(function (){
     grid.bind("filter", function (e) {
        if ((e.filter == null) ) {

            mymanualretrieve();              
        }
        if (e.filter!=null) {
            tempFilter = e.filter.filters;
        }
//i don't want the default filtering. to prevent that i am clearing it out
        e.filter = grid.dataSource.filter({});}
```

I have one dropdown where i should call retrieve again with the filters applied.so i am trying like below in change event of drop down.

```
if (tempFilter != null && tempFilter != undefined) {
    grid.dataSource.filter({ tempFilter });

        mymanualretrieve();
        tempFilter = grid.dataSource.filter().filters;
//I need to prevent default filtering here as well, but on applying the below code, my manual retrieve is not queried based on filters 
        grid.dataSource.filter({});
```

After this changes dcument.ready also doesn't get hit on filtering

Answer (score 1):

> custom filter options for every column: asp.net MVC

```
columns.Bound(c => c.columnName).Format("{0}%").Filterable(
ftb=>ftb.Cell(cell=>cell.ShowOperators(true))
.Extra(false)
.Operators(op=>op.ForNumber(fn=>fn.Clear()
    .IsEqualTo(CommonResource.GridFilter_IsEqualTo)
)))
.Title("Column Name");
```